# Is it possible to debug plugins with Xcode?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, mac

I am mac user and I want to write a Wordpress plugin. Does Xcode work for me or do I need a different and specific IDE for this?

Comment: Have you read the description of Xcode?  "Xcode is Apple's powerful integrated development environment for creating great apps for Mac, iPhone, and iPad."

So....probably not a good choice for writing PHP code for a NON-Mac or iOS app...

Answer (score 1):

For simple editing and testing you'll need an editor that supports PHP, JavaScript, and jQuery. For more advanced debugging (server side debugging ) you'll need an editor that supports Zend Debuger or xdebug(?).

So look to see if Xcode supports your requirements.

Comment: thanks for the answer but what do you mean by server side debugging?

Comment: PHP is, at least in the case of websites, a server side language; meaning the code is executed on the server before it presented to the user. JavaScript and jQuery are client side, they execute on the client within the browser. Server side debugging is the ability to debug code on the server thru your browser. Setting break points, seeing stack traces, and other messages line by line as the code executes.